# Save UITableView items to Array

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I have a UITableView with 5 names: Bob, Nick, Sim, Tom and Phil. Each name has it´s own row.

How can i save these as a array like this:

```
var mineSpillere: ["Bob", "Nick", "Sim", "Tom", "Phil"]
```

I don´t want to save it myself, because it is possible to add more names to the list, and then I also want the array to be updated with the new names. How can I do this?

Hope you understand my question. Sorry for bad English and bad grammar.

Comment: Are you asking how to create an array filled with the names from the UITableView?

Comment: @FrankBoyne - Yes, correct!

Answer (score 1):

Declare a names array

```
var names = [String]()
```

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath, before you return the cell

```
names.append(cell.textLabel!.text!)
```

Comment: just replace the ? with a ! - However your screen shot would make it seem as if you're adding names back to the same array they are populated from.

Comment: Yes, it work now. But somehow when i open another view controller and go back to the same view controller, the names i added are gone, how come?